# I have doubts concerning the tense to use

Tags: tense

Take a look at this sentence:

> I'd like to see them winning

I was wondering whether I could use this sentence in order to express the wish that I want them to win although I don't know whether this will happen.
So, should I have used this one instead:

> I'd like to see them who win.

`

Comment: It's probably more idiomatic to say _I'd like to see them win_, or (even better) _I'd like them to win_.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

- I'd like to see them winning

Will express a desire to watch them while they are winning, which is not what you want.

- I'd like to see them win

May be what you want. However, it may be better to use:

- I want them to win

Or

- I wish they won

You can also say:

- I'd like them to win

Answer (score 0):

You want "I'd like to see them win".

"I'd like to see them who win" is not grammatical (it would be grammatical, but mean something what, if it used "they" instead of "them"), and "I'd like to see them winning" is not idiomatic.